# Retrieving Documents from Documentum based on the folders name

Tags: documentum

I am buildng a system that integrates the entities from different data stores on to a unified interface. The eventual target is to build a system that has a capability of querying objects located in multiple datastores on the basis of a unique keys. One of the our datastores is Documentum in which we are keeping all of our documents foldered by their unique names (Keys). The multiple data stores are having a same unique name for a particular entity. The only show stopper here is to get a list of the documents associated with the unique name of certain entity and retrieve the document from documentation. I am searching for a way (a query, or a procedure) to get this task to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all the documents under a folder using the `folder` predicate in a DQL query:

```
select * from dm_document where folder('/mycabinet/myfolders/uniquefolder', DESCEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is to add a new Documentum Type with a custom attribute to store your unique key.  Then you can query directly on that attribute.  If you would like to try this route, you should create a new Type that inherits from `dm_document`.

Then, your query could be like this:

```
select * from my_new_type where my_custom_attribute = <unique_key>
```

Folders can be a good solution if it helps you to organize and navigate the data, but they can also create some unique performance challenges.  I would suggest against them if your dataset is very large and you don't need to navigate the folder structure.